# Cannot find class [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] for bean with name 'mailSender' defined

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am writing a spring mail program:

```
@Service("LeaveEmail")
public class LeaveEmail {
    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleMailMessage alertMailMessage;
    public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {  
        this.mailSender = mailSender;  
    }       
    public boolean sendMail(LeaveApplyForm leaveApplyForm)
    {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

        EmpRegistrationForm empRegistrationForm=new EmpRegistrationForm();
        String to=leaveApplyForm.getFirstApprover();

    //  String to1=leaveApplyForm.getFinalApprover();
        String text=leaveApplyForm.getReason();         
        String from=empRegistrationForm.getEmail();
        String subject="Application for the Leave";

        message.setFrom(from);          
                message.setTo(to);          
                message.setSubject(subject);            
                message.setText(text);          
                mailSender.send(message);           

    return true;    

    }
}
```

and my spring-servlet.xml is:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">  

   <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />

<property name="port" value="587" />

<property name="username" value="dattatraykotaledz@gmail.com" />

<property name="password" value="dattSkotale" />

<property name="javaMailProperties">

        <props>

            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>

            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>

            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.gmail.com</prop>

        </props>
            </property>
```

And I am getting this error as soon as I start the Server:

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]
17:25:14,633 DEBUG XmlBeanDefinitionReader:216 - Loaded 15 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
17:25:14,633 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:525 - Bean factory for WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e13e07: defining beans [adminLoginController,empLeaveApplyController,empRegisterController,LeaveEmail,profileController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,messageSource,localeChangeInterceptor,localeResolver,handlerMapping,mailSender]; root of factory hierarchy
17:25:14,671 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:334 - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'mailSender'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] for bean with name 'mailSender' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:612)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:609)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:432)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1246)
    ... 30 more
17:25:14,674 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:217 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
17:25:14,674 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:430 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
17:25:14,681 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:504 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
17:25:14,683 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:458 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
17:25:14,705 DEBUG ConfigurationClassUtils:74 - Could not find class file for introspecting factory methods: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:45)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:609)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:432)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4058)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
17:25:14,730 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:334 - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'mailSender'
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl] for bean with name 'mailSender' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:609)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:49
```

can anyone help me with this problem?
also I made some changes in spring-servlet.xml then It is giving ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable error which I do not understand please help with this.

Answer (score 31):

At some point org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl was moved to the dependency spring-context-support.

Ensure that you have: the artifact spring-context-support
included in your project 
example(if using maven):

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Link to context support versions: [Link to context support versions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support)

Comment: How did you figure this out? I searched the docs thoroughly but didn't find anything.

Answer (score -4):

You need to make sure you have mail.jar on your classpath

[See the spring docs for more info](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mail-introduction)

Comment: The stacktrace says  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.  That is part of spring and not in mail.jar