# ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jboss

My code is built in maven and using jBoss 6 and java 7

The code is working fine on local machine but when i try running war on server i an getting error

> ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]

I tried using aop jar but still no success

Can some one explain me the error and how to solve it

Comment: Dd you get the same error about missing `ConvertingComparator`?

Comment: It's impossible to tell you why your code doesn't work when we can't see your code. If you want help with code, you must include the *relevant* portions of that code here, in the question itself.

Comment: @krzyk on local system i am not getting any error

Comment: I am using spring 3.1.0 and could not find class ConvertingComparator in
org/springframework/core/convert/converter any idea how can i resolve it ?

Comment: try deleting the spring-asm jar , it may be conflicting with some other (just keep an backup in case)

Comment: Have you sanitized this pom.xml and removed internal dependencies? The exception that you have provided references class `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConvertingComparator` that belongs to a newer version of the Spring Framework than what you have declared and does not appear in the dependency graph generated by this pom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is failing during the creation of your **@Beans**. In particular, it is failing because *NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConvertingComparator* which means it can't find the Class definition for "ConvertingComparator". The earliest documentation I can find on the ConvertingComparator is [Spring
3.2.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConvertingComparator.html). Bear in mind, you are using **Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE**. I tried running a basic Spring project using your POM and ran into similar issues using the spring version you provided. I also ran into conflicts with **Spring 3.2.0**. I recommend using **Spring 4.3.5.RELEASE** in your POM. I had no issues running my basic example after setting the properties you have to:

```
<properties> 
        <org.springframework.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

That being said, you may have other issues in your code as well. It is difficult to provide a holistic solution without more information.

**EDIT:**

So here are all your spring dependencies:

spring-beans

spring-web

spring-webmvc

spring-tx

spring-jdbc

So first lets talk about redundancy. **[spring-webmvc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE)** actually contains **spring-web** and **spring-beans**. You can therefore remove those dependencies from your POM as they are redundant. **[spring-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.3.RELEASE)** contains **spring-tx**, rendering that inclusion also redundant. You can remove all of those from your POM right now for clean up.

In your comment, you mentioned a new error being thrown in regards to *package org.springframework.mail* not being found. This package is found in **spring-context-support**. Spring context support is actually found in the **spring-webmvc** as well as an optional dependency. (so you would have to include it manually)

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829749/cannot-find-class-org-springframework-mail-javamail-javamailsenderimpl-for-bea) thread, that package was moved into context-support separately. My guess is that you are trying to specifically use some of the objects available in the .mail package and because you were not including it, it wasn't being found. With more information as to your project, the more we can dive into why 3.2 did not work and 4.1 does work. Specifics aside, what this all means is that the 3.2 dependencies you were calling did not expose the required packages, but the 4.1 dependencies do.

Comment: now its giving me error as package org.springframework.mail does not exist

Comment: Yeah I had similar issues when using older versions. My guess is some of the spring modules you are using, like spring-beans, may not have contained everything needed to resolve some of the other dependencies. If you want to use an older spring you may need to use different spring modules like spring-core. I'll post back with a definitive answer as to what the 3.x.x modules are missing.

Comment: @JustCode007 I left an update with more information for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stopped the process, I mean that particular bean could be in-use ?